# AWS S3 Java 2.X Client configuration issue

Tags: java, aws-java-sdk-2.x, aws-s3-client

```
 StaticCredentialsProvider provider = StaticCredentialsProvider.create(AwsBasicCredentials.create("Access key ID", "Access secret key"));
S3Client s3 = S3Client.builder().credentialsProvider(provider).build())
List<Bucket> buckets = s3.listBuckets().buckets();
for (Bucket bucket : buckets) {
  System.out.println("bucket name: " + bucket.name());
}
```

I am trying this code to connect to S3 storage to get the bucket details but always getting the error **Unable to load region from any of the providers in the chain software.amazon.awssdk.regions.providers.DefaultAwsRegionProviderChain.** Not sure what is wrong here. Please help.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/region-selection.html#automatically-determine-the-aws-region-from-the-environment , it is not "out of the box", you need to have at least an ec2 instance running(4.)...simpler: providing config files(3.)/setting env variable(2.)/setting programmatically(1.)

Answer (score 0):

Simply you need to tell the S3 service what region your buckets reside in:

```
StaticCredentialsProvider provider = StaticCredentialsProvider.create(
        AwsBasicCredentials.create("Access key ID", "Access secret key"));

S3Client s3 = S3Client.builder().credentialsProvider(provider)
        .region(Region.EU_WEST_2)  // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< you need a region here
        .build();

List<Bucket> buckets = s3.listBuckets().buckets();
for (Bucket bucket : buckets) {
    System.out.println("bucket name: " + bucket.name());
}
```

Comment: Hello Andrew, Thanks for your reply. 

Here, i don't want to mention the specific region here. wanted to connect the default region of my account.

Comment: BTW, i am not using the amazon S3 but using a S3 compatible service provider

Comment: "wanted to connect the default region of my account" - yes! but how does the S3 library know this when you use the _explicit_ `StaticCredentialsProvider`?   When using CLI for AWS, for example, you ALSO have define a default.  This is _implicilty_ found in `~/.aws/config`.  (Other `CredentialsProviders` are available that use environment variables to acquire such default from configuration files like the CLI uses.)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am able to get it work with the following code.

**bold S3Client s3Client = S3Client.builder()
 .endpointProvider(new S3EndpointProvider() {
@Override
 public CompletableFuture<Endpoint> resolveEndpoint(S3EndpointParams endpointParams) {
return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(Endpoint.builder()
 .url(URI.create("https://x2u2.or.idrivee2-61.com"))
.build());
 }
}).region(Region.US_EAST_1)
  .credentialsProvider(() -> AwsBasicCredentials.create("", ""))
 .build();

Comment: However, i am getting the below error while creating the bucket.

An error occurred when parsing the HTTP request PUT at '/'

Bucket creation code :


CreateBucketRequest bucketRequest = CreateBucketRequest.builder()
                     .bucket(bucketName)
                     .build(); 
             s3Client.createBucket(bucketRequest);

Comment: Please start a new Question if there is a new problem creating a bucket.  It is too difficult to follow in comments.  But seems suspicious is that the bucket name looks to be empty or just a slash given what I can see of the error message "/"

Comment: Will ask this as another question . Thanks.